# How to create custom text to speech with python and audio files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, text-to-speech

I have an audio (mp3) files for each letter. I want to create own text to speech. I am using `os.system("start D:\\letters\\a.mp3")` , but if I want code to say some word, only last letter is played. What is an other way to play audio files letter by letter ? So like text to speech.

I am currently on Windows but planning to move on Linux, so need some multiplatform library that is needed for that type of project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to try to discourage you from this. However you'll need the entire Phonetic alphabet, and a way to break a word down into that. If you are just looking for a program that will just play the letters of the words you can always use VLC with a for loop.

```
import vlc
for i in [list]
    audio = vlc.MediaPlayer("path")
    audio.play()
```

If you're looking to just use text to speech there are plenty of APIs already out there. [Google](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech) is a really good option. [pyttx3](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/) also isn't too shabby and is a good-to-go python module.